# High Voltage Capacitor Identification

Tags: capacitor, identification

I'm unable to identify or source the capacitor pictured to try and track down a spec sheet. Do you guys have any idea what capacitor model this is? Additional pictures here https://imgur.com/a/0H1hTB8

Dimensions are 35mm W x 30mm D x ~38mm T and looks to have 4 pins on the base. Pictures in album are two different capacitors that look to be exactly the same with slightly different markings.
[image]

Comment: For context, please [edit] and add what device the board is from. Also, people are less likely to visit an external site to view the images, it's better to include all relevant photo in your post.

Comment: Hope there is a discharge resistor across it... that could give a *nasty* shock. Photoflash?

Comment: For some reason I had issues adding multiple photos to the post as I certainly agree. 
This is from a board that provides a high voltage, high energy spark.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact manufacturer, but it looks very similar to the 4-pin version of the vishay dc-link metalised film cap MKP1848H54012K, or the Kemet C4AFBBW4400F3OK

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'll look into both of those models